# Cannot read property `scopeLabel` of undefined on Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I'm using luma theme. Nothing haven't been changed I only installed latest version from Magento connect. Added test category and product. This problem is only on product detail page. Other pages works fine 
On Product Page i have js error:

> knockout.js:3012 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "attr:
>   function (){return {'data-config-scope':$data.scopeLabel} }"
>
> Message: Cannot read property `scopeLabel` of undefined

[image]

I tried `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and clear cache etc but nothing changed.
Is it bug magento?
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When making a copy the content (ex: Product labels) in Admin. There are some **Java script code lines (Knockout Js) which are added to product description** (WYSIWYG html editor) with content. So, this issue occurs.

[image]

We need to clean the product description.

**[It may not be a Magento bug. Seem that it's the default WYSIWYG html editor behaviour](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6679)**.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mainly if you're using a custom theme which inherits from other (Magento) theme and dependencies haven't been established correctly between the pub/static files and theme files.

You can get rid of pub/static/frontend files and regenerated them by either issuing following command (production mode only)

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

or if in dev mode and you've got grunt setup then issue

```
grunt clean
grunt exec
grunt less
```

You can also clear cache and remove var/view_preprocessed, var/view/generation, var/cache directories after static files have been regenerated.

Comment: I did it but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you provide bit more info on your setup, what theme are you using, what changes have been made to the theme in use etc. ?

Comment: I'm using luma theme.
Nothing haven't been changed
I only installed latest version from Magento connect. Added test category and product.
This problem is only on product detail page. Other pages works fine

Comment: It looks like something to do with the static content not being deployed correctly, if none of the above works I'll say go for the re-installation and if possible use composer install method [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Helped to me:

```
1. Deleting all products
2. Deleting all categories (Excluding: "Default Category")
3. $ bin/magento indexer:reindex -vvv;
4. $ rm -rf pub/static/*
5. $ rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
6. $ bin/magento cache:clean -vvv
7. $ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Customtheme/name --language en_US; bin/magento cache:flush -vvv
```